# Monero GUI with Ledger Nano S. Synchronizing forever and not showing transaction received

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization, transaction-confirmation

Sent from Kucoin, which says transaction was completed hours ago, but not showing up in my wallet. The GUI says `Synchronizing Wallet` and `Synchronizing Daemon` for a long time now. The wallet does display my old balance, but not including this new transaction.

I just restarted the wallet, this is what the daemon log says, should it be of help:

```
[7/10/21 6:11 PM] 2021-07-11 01:11:06.921 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-release)
Height: 1, target: 2402117 (4.16299e-05%)
Downloading at 1 kB/s
Next needed pruning seed: 1
2 peers
198.46.210.157:18080 0000000000000000 before_handshake 0 0 0 kB/s, 0 blocks / 0 MB queued
188.40.207.205:18080 191d5c893a560da1 normal 180 2402117 1 kB/s, 0 blocks / 0 MB queued
0 spans, 0 MB
```

Status says:

```
[7/10/21 6:14 PM] 2021-07-11 01:13:43.489 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-release)
Height: 1/2402120 (0.0%) on mainnet, bootstrapping from 49.12.8.194:18089 was used before, not mining, net hash 0 H/s, v14, 16(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 2m 58s
```

I am on Mac OS 10.14.6, no antivirus software, Tor, or i2p. I use a VPN.

GUI version: 0.17.2.2-937cb98 (Qt 5.12.8)

Embedded Monero version: 0.17.2.0-release

Wallet restore height: 2254263

Wallet mode: Simple mode

I want to make sure I receive the funds and I don't know if I can do something to cause it to synchronize should that be my issue. I greatly appreciate any assistance, thank you.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue?

Comment: Not yet, I am working with you on Reddit under khemtrailfrank username to resolve it. I was going to delete my question here but could not find a link to do so. I'm currently seeing if I can access my private key, I'll respond on Reddit. Many thanks.

Comment: For visibility purposes, resolved here: https://www.reddit.com/r/monerosupport/comments/ohtqhz/monero_gui_with_ledger_nano_s_not_showing/h5f1acr/